# Is there a reliable way to find out last accessed date in MOSS 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

Site Usage report in Site Administration does not help. I also tried querying
the SQL Db to read daylastaccessed but that would not help. 'GetUsageData' method of the Object model only reads data for last 1 month and the "Most Recent Day" value is not accurate. Also I want a report of the last 6 months.

The search crawler too modifies the last accessed date.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting information from the IIS Logs. 
Otherwise write a custom http module to record new sessions (and ignore the search crawler).

Answer (score 1):

IIS Logs is a great suggestion. If you already have a tracking system setup, you could add a web tracking bug to your master page.